# Difficulties in understanding this elm function

Tags: elm, type-annotation

I am learning elm, I've read the documentation and now I'm trying to annotate all the examples trying to explain what happens in each function.

[This exercise](http://elm-lang.org/examples/zip-codes) is taking me quite some time to understand.

1. What does the next type annotation mean? I get the first parameter is a `String` and the last `Html`, but what about the middle one? Is it a `Result` which is composed by a `String` field and a `List String` field?

`view : String -> Result String (List String) -> Html`

2. Almost the same as the above, what does those nested types mean?

`results : Signal.Mailbox (Result String (List String))`

I'll leave the async bit for another question, many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Result` abstracts an operation that could succeed or fail. It is defined as

```
type Result error value
    = Ok value
    | Err error
```

If the operation succeeds the values will be `Ok value`, otherwise, if it fails, it will be `Err error`. In your case, the suceed value will be a list of strings, while the error value will be a single message.

For the second point, the thing is similar, `results` is a mailbox that contains a `Result`, which will be either `Ok (List String)` or `Err String`

Comment: Many thanks! I will be posting more of these while I learn elm :P